# Gorm equivalent for SQL

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Simple one - what is the best way in Grails/Gorm to get the same effect as this SQL query:

SELECT YEAR(date) as SalesYear,
         MONTH(date) as SalesMonth,
         SUM(Price) AS TotalSales
    FROM Sales
GROUP BY YEAR(date), MONTH(date)
ORDER BY YEAR(date), MONTH(date)

Comment: You can use HQL, see executeQuery.

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't help much - kind of like saying, you can use Java - see the javadoc...

Comment: Well, the Grails documentation is more than a javadoc, I think is not a fair example, but I answered your question and pointed the sources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [executeQuery](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/executeQuery.html) method of a domain class allows you to run [HQL](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#hql) queries.

If you look at some examples, you will notice that the [Hibernate Query Language](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/queryhql.html) remembers a lot SQL, but is object-oriented.

From the Grails docs:

> The executeQuery method allows the execution of arbitrary HQL queries.
>   HQL queries can return domain class instances, or Arrays of specified
>   data when the query selects individual fields or calculated values.

So in your case, the query will return an array of the specified data, since don't matches with a Domain Class, but you will be able to iterate over this data.

Assuming that you mapped your sales table as Sales domain class:

```
class Sales {
  Date date
  BigDecimal price
  ...
  static mapping = {
    ...
  }
}


def result = Sales.executeQuery("SELECT YEAR(date) as SalesYear, MONTH(date) as SalesMonth, SUM(Price) AS TotalSales FROM Sales GROUP BY YEAR(date), MONTH(date) ORDER BY YEAR(date), MONTH(date)")

//iterate over the result
result.each { sales ->
  println sales[0] //year
  println sales[1] //month
  println sales[2] //total
}
```